# scroll lags when trying to listen to scroll position in android jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, compose-recomposition

I'm using Jetpack compose in my project. I have a scrollable column. I want to show a column as the top bar when the user scrolls the screen. For this purpose, I listen to the state of the scroll in this way:

```kotlin
val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
    Box {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(paddingValues)
                .verticalScroll(scrollState)
        ) {
          ...
          ...
          ...
        }

        TopBar(scrollOffset = (scrollState.value * 0.1))
    }
```

and the TopBar is another composable:

```
@Composable
fun HiddenTopBar(scrollOffset: Double, onSearchListener: () -> Unit) {
    val offset = if (-50 + scrollOffset < 0) (-50 + scrollOffset).dp else 0.dp
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(50.dp)
            .offset(y = offset)
            .background(MaterialTheme.colors.secondary)
            .padding(vertical = MaterialTheme.space.small)
    ) {
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem is that due to constant recomposition, the scroll lags, and it is not smooth. Is there any way I can implement it more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's because of constant recomposition in [performance documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance#use-derivedstateof).

If you were checking a state derived from scroll state such as if it's scrolled you could go for derivedState but you need it on each change, `nestedScrollConnection` might help i guess.

This sample might help you how to implement it

```
 @Composable
private fun NestedScrollExample() {

    val density = LocalDensity.current
    val statusBarTop = WindowInsets.statusBars.getTop(density)


    val toolbarHeight = 100.dp
    val toolbarHeightPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { toolbarHeight.roundToPx().toFloat() }

    // our offset to collapse toolbar
    val toolbarOffsetHeightPx = remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

    val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
        object : NestedScrollConnection {
            override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
                val delta = available.y
                val newOffset = toolbarOffsetHeightPx.value + delta
                toolbarOffsetHeightPx.value =
                    newOffset.coerceIn(-(2 * statusBarTop + toolbarHeightPx), 0f)
                return Offset.Zero
            }
        }
    }
    Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            // attach as a parent to the nested scroll system
            .nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(
                    PaddingValues(
                        top = toolbarHeight + 8.dp,
                        start = 8.dp,
                        end = 8.dp,
                        bottom = 8.dp
                    )
                )
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            ,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
        ) {
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(2000.dp))
        }
        TopAppBar(modifier = Modifier
            .height(toolbarHeight)
            .offset { IntOffset(x = 0, y = toolbarOffsetHeightPx.value.roundToInt()) },
            elevation = 2.dp,
            backgroundColor = Color.White,
            title = { Text("toolbar offset is ${toolbarOffsetHeightPx.value}") })
    }
}
```

Comment: this solution has an error, it keeps adding the offset value even if the scroll is reached at the end or the top. So, in this case, for example, if the user keeps swiping their finger on the screen while the scroll is, let's say, at the top, the offset increase. So now, if he scrolls the page down because the offset is increased a lot, the top bar won't show until he scrolls down enough.

Comment: You can add a y.coerceAtMost() to limit offset at desired upper limit. This is just a demonstration that you can use nestedScroll instead of observing scrollState. `-50 + scrollOffset).coerceAtMost(0f)` for instance makes sure that scrollOffset is never bigger than 50

Comment: Ok, it gets way better. But still, when the toolbar wants to be shown or hidden, the scroll lags. The rest of the time is ok. I accept the answer. But I would appreciate it if you let me know in case of a better way.

Comment: If you are okay using Material design3 which is in alpha stage at the moment check TopAppbars there. M3 has scrolling behavior you can select from like we do with View counterpart

Comment: And my another suggestion would be to try Modifier.graphicsLayer{translationY} instead of Modifier.offset{}. It might help. I'm using both never had performance issue but maybe with a complex composable like your TopAppbar it might be an issue. Can't say for sure

Comment: Oh, thanks for your suggestions. I'll try both.